# I removed my header widget in blogger by mistake. How do I reinstall it?

Tags: blogger

I'm new here i have a problem I was going to change the banner on the header and removed the header widget altogether by mistake. Is there a way to install the header widget back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the header widget,

Go to Layout > on the header section, you should have "Add a Gadget" link. Click on this, a new window will open with list of Blogger gadgets.

Select "Page Header" gadget from the list.